# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.IEnumberable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm receiving this error in my Linq statement ---

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'hcgames.ObjectClasses.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartCartAddon'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

From this query

```
        ShoppingCartItems items = Cart.GetAllItems();
        ShoppingCartCartAddons addons = Cart.GetAllAddons();

      var  stuff = from x in items
                    select new ShoppingCartItem()
                    {
                        ProductID = x.ProductID,
                        Quantity = x.Quantity,
                        Name = x.Name,
                        Price = x.Price,
                        Weight = x.Weight,
                        Addons =  (from y in addons
                                  where y.ShoppingCartItemID == x.ID
                                  select y)
                    };
```

I can not figure out how to cast this properly.  Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post `ShoppingCartCartAddons` and `ShoppingCartItems.Addons` signatures ?

Comment: namespace hcgames.ObjectClasses.ShoppingCart
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ShoppingCartItem
    {
        public ShoppingCartItem();
        public ShoppingCartItem(DataRow dr);

        public ShoppingCartCartAddons Addons { get; set; }
        public string CartID { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public long ProductID { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace hcgames.ObjectClasses.ShoppingCart
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ShoppingCartCartAddons : Collection<ShoppingCartCartAddon>
    {
        public ShoppingCartCartAddons();
    }
}

Comment: namespace hcgames.ObjectClasses.ShoppingCart
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ShoppingCartCartAddon
    {
        public ShoppingCartCartAddon();
        public ShoppingCartCartAddon(DataRow dr);

        public string LabelText { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int ProductAddonID { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public long ShoppingCartAddonID { get; set; }
        public long ShoppingCartItemID { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Aight, edited my answer, and for future reference, you can edit your question in order to add more details (and shiny formatted code) instead of doing it in comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the code you posted, there's at least one ways you can resolve it. The simpler, less elegant is to modify your `ShoppingCartItem.Addons` signature like the following, since your ShoppingCartCartAddons collection does not have any other functionalities :

```
namespace hcgames.ObjectClasses.ShoppingCart 
{ 
    [Serializable] 
    public class ShoppingCartItem 
    {
        public ShoppingCartItem(); 
        public ShoppingCartItem(DataRow dr); 
        public IEnumerable<ShoppingCartCartAddon> Addons { get; set; } 
        public string CartID { get; set; } 
        public int ID { get; set; } 
        public string Image { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Price { get; set; } 
        public long ProductID { get; set; } 
        public int Quantity { get; set; } 
        public decimal Weight { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Explanation : you are basicly trying to initialize a `Collection<ShoppingCartCartAddon>` implementation, `ShoppingCartCartAddons` from an `IEnumerable<ShoppingCartCartAddon>`, thus compiler goes wonkers.

Otherwise, you can define a contructor for `ShoppingCartCartAddons` which takes in an `IEnumerable<ShoppingCartCartAddon>` to intialize itself.

Comment: I do have it definied as ShoppingCartCartAddons.  Posting code now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm shooting in the dark since I don't know what type `ShoppingCartItem.Addons` is, but judging from the error, I would say it's expecting that type to be `hcgames.ObjectClasses.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartCartAddon`

Your LINQ query is turning an `IEnumerable<ShoppingCartCartAddon>`. You could adding `.FirstOrDefault()` to the LINQ Query to see if that clears things up.